# Define "enum"-type depending on generics

Tags: vhdl

I am writing a statemachine, which has a generic parameter, and some states existence depends on this. Since I have my states defined in something like an enum (don't know the vhdl term for it), I wonder if I can define this enum depending on the generic somewhat like so:

```
generic(x: bool);  -- in the entity
....

architecture ...
    if x then generate
        type states_t is (State1, State2, State3ifX)
    else
        type states_t is (State1, State2)
    end generate;
    variable state : states_t;
begin
   case state is
       ....
       if x then generate
           when State3ifX =>
                ...
       end if;
   end case
end architecture;
```

Do I have to carry the dead weight (logic for state3, danger to drop into it (does not matter in my case since I do not expect radiation), additional bit since `ceil(ld(3))=2 > ld(2)=1`), or is there a possibility to strip unnecessary state(s)?

(In my case there are several states that could be stripped, however seperate architectures are not worth while the effort)

Comment: @scottb: `vhdl` has not much in the terms of data structures...       and going with a vector that I dynamically size would make the code quit unreadable since I would have to name the states with series of bits, that I adjust in length accoridngly ( sure `others => '0' would help, but still)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to achieve what you need.

On the upside, your concern about having to *"carry the dead weight (logic for state3, danger to drop into it)"* is not something you need to worry about - the synthesizer will optimise the logic away, so the state register will only be as big as it needs to be for the states you can actually reach.

Comment: as this at least awnsers to my concern about size/illegal states i accept this awnser over the detailed one, which did not quite awnser to my concerns

Answer (score 2):

you can define the "states"-type in a process that is optionally generated using a generic. see a reference example below:

```
entity blabla is
   generic(sel: std_logic := '0');
port(
...

architecture Behavioral of blabla is
begin

q1: if sel='0' generate
p: process(clk)
    type t_state is (s1, s2, s3);
    variable state: t_state;
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
       ...
    end if;
end process;
end generate;

q2: if sel='1' generate
p: process(clk)
    type t_state is (s1, s2);
    variable state: t_state;
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        ...
    end if;
end process;
end generate;
```

Comment: +1 for a possibility, but duplicating all the `common` states, is unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score -1):

I know its an old tread but still a hit on google so Im adding how Im doing it

**label: if x generate**

*declarations <- put types, signals & attribures here !!!!*

**begin**

```
ur code
```

**end generate label;**

You might want to consider second architecture or even simpler just a different entity - just another vhd file with slightly different name (like _x1, then _x2)

I find "genercis system" not really practical in more advanced cases (to much *bloat-code* to write), and then u might use different synthezisers so two archoitecture with one entity might not work, generate with decalrations inside might not work.... I would create different vhd for that - it will work in all the cases)

Cheers